# Intersection of 4 convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: convex-geometry

Does there exist an example of four convex sets lying in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the intersection of every 3 of them contains a unit-length interval but the intersection of all 4 of them does not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Consider the four rectangles

`(0  ,  0),  (1  ,  0),   (1  ,1.5),   (0  ,1.5)
(0.5,  0),  (1.5,  0),   (1.5,1.5),   (0.5,1.5)
(0  ,  0),  (0  ,  1),   (1.5,  1),   (1.5,  0)
(0  ,0.5),  (0  ,1.5),   (1.5,1.5),   (1.5,0.5)`

Then the intersection of each triple is a $1 \times 0.5$ (or $0.5 \times 1$) rectangle, and the intersection of all four is a $0.5 \times 0.5$ square.